# Will a node with no incoming arc or no out coming arc affect the maximum flow?

Tags: network-flow

So in a maximum flow question, say if we have a node which is not $s$ nor $t$, if it has no incoming arc, can we delete it without affecting the maximum flow? What if it has no output arc? How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. If it has, say, no outcoming edge, there can be no flow routed over this node. Otherwise the flow conservation constraint for this node ($v$)
$$\sum_{(u,v) \in E} f_{uv} - \underbrace{\sum_{(v,w) \in E} f_{vw}}_{= 0} = 0$$
is violated if you have incoming flow.

Comment: I see, many thanks!